how to make my single header also be compatible to be compiled as module
I have some little library header primary focused to be just included using preprocessor. But i also want to let somebody compile it to a module. As i assume now i can just add some lines modues does require and they will be ignored unless compiled to a module. I have made a .ixx interface but when tryed to compile there were some errors.
The iscstdlibc++.h
/**
 * This is some std library contains some common declarations.
 */
export module iscstdlibcpp;
#ifndef _ISC_STD_LIB
#define _ISC_STD_LIB
//#define _ISC_STD_LIB_CPP
//#if defined(__cpp_modules) && (defined(__clang_modules_build) || //defined(__cplusplus_modules) || defined(MODULE))
//#define 
//#endif
#include <map>
#include <vector>
#include <deque>
#include <string>
#include <any>
#include <variant>
#include <string_view>
#include <stdexcept>
/**
 * @brief For the C++ here are common class declarations and structures
 * 
*/
namespace ISC_STD {
// my header declaratioms

} // namespace __ISC_STD


#endif // ISC_STD_LIB_CPP

The .ixx file is same except that there are only declarations
/**
 * This is some std library contains some common declarations.
 */
export module iscstdlibcpp;

#include <map>
#include <vector>
#include <deque>
#include <string>
#include <any>
#include <variant>
#include <string_view>
#include <stdexcept>
/**
 * @brief For the C++ here are common class declarations and structures
 * 
*/
namespace ISC_STD {
// like in header but only declarations without the code
} // namespace __ISC_STD

tryed to compile using command (i use Windows):
PS C:\programming\ISC\lib> clang++ iscstdlibc++.h -std=c++23 -c -Xclang -emit-module-interface iscstdlibc++.ixx -o iscstdlibcpp.pcm 
clang++: warning: treating 'c-header' input as 'c++-header' when in C++ mode, this behavior is deprecated [-Wdeprecated]
clang++: warning: iscstdlibc++.ixx: 'linker' input unused [-Wunused-command-line-argument]
In file included from iscstdlibc++.h:11:
In file included from C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.39.33519\include\map:8:
In file included from C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.39.33519\include\yvals_core.h:501:
In file included from C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.39.33519\include\vcruntime.h:58:
In file included from C:\cclang\clang\LLVM\lib\clang\17\include\vadefs.h:18:
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.39.33519\include\vadefs.h:155:18: error: declaration of '__va_start' in the global module follows declaration in
      module iscstdlibcpp
  155 |     void __cdecl __va_start(va_list* , ...);
      |                  ^
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.39.33519\include\vadefs.h:155:18: note: previous declaration is here
In file included from iscstdlibc++.h:11:
In file included from C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.39.33519\include\map:11:
In file included from C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.39.33519\include\tuple:13:
In file included from C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.39.33519\include\__msvc_iter_core.hpp:10:
In file included from C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.39.33519\include\utility:22:
In file included from C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.39.33519\include\cstdlib:12:
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.22621.0\ucrt\stdlib.h:311:22: error: declaration of '_rotl' in the global module follows declaration in module iscstdlibcpp
  311 | unsigned int __cdecl _rotl(
      |                      ^
 // just c++ std lib flow ...
fatal error: too many errors emitted, stopping now [-ferror-limit=]
20 errors generated.


I Have found a solution. The issue is related to the std lib.
module;
#include <map>
#include <vector>
#include <deque>
#include <string>
#include <any>
#include <string_view>
#include <stdexcept>
export module iscstdlibcpp;
// my code as above

Then i compiled using command:
clang++ -std=c++23 iscstdlibc++.h --precompile -o iscstdlibc++_md.pcm

Now my header works as needed and also can be compiled to a module if somebody would need without further changes to the header.
